# Extremely poor recording quality - Asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk, centos7, audio-recording

I had a server all setup that was working pretty well, but as I was doing some security things I screwed it up and had to reinstall everything. Now call recordings are horrible and sound like this:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=58238805044662381352&t=58238805044662381352302451

Opening the file in Adobe Audition allowed me to adjust the playback rate, when I played it back at 2X speed, it sounded a little better, but there was still distortion. The distortion makes it sound robotic, slower and with clicking noises mixed in.

I have tried it as gsm and wav, tried setting the volume only because when I downloaded it to my PC it was really hard to hear, but on playback within asterisk the volume was fine. I also tried upgrading sox.

The call is coming in from a GSM gateway to the Asterisk 11 server which is a Dell R610 with 16GB RAM, RAID 10 HDD setup with nothing else to do other than record this call, so there shouldn't be any load issues. When I call from a phone to a phone, the audio sounds great on the handset The recordings sounded fine before I reinstalled everything, any tips?

Here is the dialplan info (but I don't think it is relevant, nor is it finished, only included to show nothing crazy happening)

```
[inbound-record]
exten => s,1,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=5)
exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=15)
exten => s,n,Playback(press)
exten => s,n,Playback(digits/1)
exten => s,n,Read(ACCOUNTNUM,digits/1,i)
exten => s,n,System(/usr/bin/mkdir /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/outboundmsgs/${ACCOUNTNUM})
exten => s,n,Set(VOLUME(TX)=6)

exten => s,n,Set(VOLUME(RX)=9)
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-record-prepend)
exten => s,n,Record(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/outboundmsgs/${ACCOUNTNUM}/tmp_greeting:wav)
exten => s,n,Wait(2)
exten => s,n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/outboundmsgs/${ACCOUNTNUM}/tmp_greeting)
exten => s,n,wait(2)
exten => s,n,Hangup
```

Comment: This is not an on-topic question, and the resolution makes it even less useful to the general public. If you delete it you will get back your lost points from downvotes, FYI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I worked till midnight last night with the tech support from OpenVox and we finally found the issue. There is something funny with their Ethernet ports on the new box where port 1 can only see slot 1, to see the others I plugged into port 2, but had left port 1 also plugged in - which effectively gave it 2 routes with the same IP.....

That would be why it was recording 50% slower, because in a round robin of receiving it would take a packet from port 1, then port 2, then port 1 again, but only 1 of them would have data. Unplugging one of them resolved all the issues.